# html/css, how to push an element on to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I've written this small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yymxb/) showing what I want, but what I would like to know is, is there away to style the `.stack-slot` elements so that they; (a) shrink to the size of their content and (b) stack vertically beneath one another as shown, using a css rule instead of `<br/>` tags?

html:

```
<span class='stack-panel vertical'>
    <span class='stack-slot'>
        <span class='content'>1</span>
    </span>
    <br/>
    <span class='stack-slot'>
        <span class='content'>2</span>
    </span>
    <br/>
    <span class='stack-slot'>
        <span class='content'>3</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.stack-panel.vertical .stack-slot
{
    /*TODO replace effect of <br/> tag*/
}
```

Comment: You should be using a list: <ul><li>...</li>...etc </ul>

Comment: semi agree, but it's not meant to be a list it's meant to be a stack panel and the semantic meaning comes from the class names in this instance.

Comment: Screen readers understand lists as semantic. They don't care about class names.

Comment: again I agree but this is being written as a visual layout tool, and needs to fit in with existing implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
.stack-panel.vertical .stack-slot {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Yymxb/4/)**

No `<br>` tags, they stack vertically, and shrink to fit their content.

Comment: thanks, I was trying just `clear:both;` hoping the answer would lay in floating them some how, just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an unrdered list for things that are grouped.

```
     <ul>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
   </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   list-style:none
}
```

Comment: But that won't resize to fit its content.

Comment: Why not? Please demonstrate.